# Real Analysis Question $\sup (A) \leq \sup (B)$

Tags: real-analysis

hi there i'd just like some one to clarify whether my thinking is correct. thanks

> Let $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and bounded with $A \subseteq B$. show that $\sup~A \leq \sup ~B$

so my thinking is this.

a set A is bounded if $\forall a  \in A~\exists ~ \alpha~$such $~|a| \leq \alpha $

consider $A \subseteq B$ since A is contained in B then $\exists~b \in B$ such that $b \notin A$ Denote the largest Such b as b' and we can break this into several cases.

Case 1: $\exists~a~\in~A~$such $~ b' < a \Rightarrow \sup A = \sup B$

Case 2: $\forall a~\in A,~a<b' \Rightarrow \sup A < \sup B$ where it necessitates $\sup B = b'$

Case 3: trivial case where $\sup A = \sup B$ anyway because the largest Element in B is also an element of A

Is this a legit answer? further is there an easier way of answering this and what indicators are there to suggest thats the easier path forward?

thank you in advance.

Comment: The line where you say $A \subset B$ implies the existance of a $b \in B$ with $b \notin A$ is wrong. Consider $A = [0,1]$ and $B = A$. Then $A \subset B$ but all $b \in B$ are also in $A$.

Comment: Your definition of a bounded set isn't quite right -- your quantifiers are backward.  It should be that there exists $\alpha$ such that for all $a\in A$, $\lvert a\rvert\leq\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sup B$ is an upper bound of $B$ and hence $b \le \sup B$
for all $b \in B$ and so $a \le \sup B$ for all $a \in A$. Hence
$\sup B$ is an upper bound for $A$ and so $\sup A \le \sup B$.

Note that the key fact here is that if $L$ is an upper bound of a set $A$ then $\sup A \le L$.